# How to trick a crawler/scanner from detecting the web technology?

Tags: php, security

I have a PHP website and I have all the URL rewriting done. Such that the PHP extensions are hidden. But somehow the webcrawlers and security scanners / vulnerability scanners are able to find my site was developed in PHP.

How do I avoid that or How do I trick them that this website was not developed through PHP ?

Comment: This setting might be relevant: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.expose-php

Comment: Crawlers can also detect the folder structure / assets of common plugins for frameworks etc and match them to the langauge. One example  would be to check for `/wp-admin` meaning wordpress.

Comment: But I have hidden almost all extensions.

Comment: Even if you strip extensions with rewrites, it's still possible to detect the extensions. One way is to access a file directly, if your web server allows it. So, `/test` might redirect internally to `/test.php` and so will `/test.php` but not `/test.xml`; this of course depends on the web server and how you've removed extensions or are filtering requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## One-of-the legitimate ways of doing it.

---

Well most web-vulnerability scanners or crawlers make use of your website headers to find out this. Say if you do this..

```
<?php
var_dump(headers_list());
```

You will get..

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(23) "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.3"
}
```

So with that information a crawler can easily make up that your site was developed with PHP.

### How to avoid this ?

You could make use of `header_remove()` in PHP for that.

As you can see from the code..

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump(headers_list());
header_remove();
var_dump(headers_list());
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(23) "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.3"
}

array(0) {
}
```

The headers are now empty.

Comment: I develop on a security scanner and I can say that this is definitely one way to cause it to fallback into other detection methods. Ours uses multiple things to determine a confidence level for what technologies a website uses. One is the headers, then it's folder structure as someone already mentioned, and then it's checksums of guessed files. We use a very large heuristic database for over 10,000 different plugins, frameworks, etc. We also examine the HTTP response codes to determine if something is blocked by an explicit rule or a broad coverage rule or if the file is not there.

Comment: As I posted in a comment, that header can be disabled with a change to this ini setting: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.expose-php Removing all headers with `header_remove()` is definitely overkill, and could easily have unforeseen side effects.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray You should type that up as an answer, because it explains why the OP is unlikely to achieve their goal.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray, Interesting... IMSoP , Yeah that is a nice one too.

Comment: I think this will solve my temporary problems as of now. I will accept your answer now, I am ready to accept other answer if someone posts better than this.

Comment: @IMSoP There, I went ahead and elaborated :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment, I develop on a security scanner which is probably similar to the one you're trying to hide certain information from.

One of the reasons this is difficult to achieve is because security scanners don't just look at one thing, usually. The one I work on uses a very large database of fingerprints to determine if specific files or behaviors represent a certain plugin, framework, site builder, or even if the website is generated in a structurally similar way to another that uses a specific tool to generate the HTML.

Once we discover one technology, we can relate it based on those fingerprints to another website that doesn't expose all of the same information or perhaps even intentionally changes it to something misleading.

A great example of this is when people change their `X-Powered-By` header to something that is not representative of what they use.

Say if you ran a PHP driven website but your `X-Powered-By` header was "Microsoft ASP.NET" or anything else. We could assume the information is false or otherwise questionable if all of your extensions end in `.php` or are hidden. There are also certain behavioral nuances that exist for other technologies, such as ASP.NET, which are the existence of structural fingerprints like the `_VIEWSTATE` strings.

Additionally, you need to keep in mind things like URL formats, POST/PUT behavior, and even what other software you run. If you run WordPress for example, it's very probable that you're using PHP.

This is only a small example. There are thousands of rules per technology which generate more and more confidence that we're right about our guess. We have a database of products that each have unique or crossed fingerprints and it has around 10,000 identified products in it.

All of this information is collected and analyzed. If we determine a website is not representing itself correctly, it flags the website and a list of pages in question for human review, at which point an analyst will manually plug away at the website and determine its technologies by hand and figure out new fingerprints for it.

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php#86623) right ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Yeah. Spoofing as ASP.NET and not having the fingerprints in the website would cause a manual review or other methods of identification to be used. It's probably best if you rewrite your URLs to be ".html" and try to fool the crawler into believing the website is statically presented. But, timing attacks can reveal whether or not content is generated... and so can some other more funky methods. In the end it's not really "bad" to let people know you use PHP. Just keep your files secured!

Comment: Nicely explained. Mike . My **+1**